# Could not access local Parse server dashboard with Mongodb

Tags: node.js, windows, mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server

I am trying to install mongodb and parse server on my windows 10 pc, after completing everything without error, I'm still unable to access the dashboard, the browser show **This site can't be reach.** Below shows the step on how I did it, please help me to identify the problem, thanks.

1. At Node.js command prompt

`cd C:\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin
mongod --auth`
**OUTPUT: waiting for connections on port 27017**

2. Launch another Node.js command prompt

`cd C:\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin
mongo
use db_parsetest`
**OUTPUT: switched to db db_parsetest**

3. Launch another Node.js command prompt

`cd C:\
parse-server --appId com.test.parsetest --masterKey parsetestkey --databaseURI mongodb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@localhost:27017/db_parsetest`
**OUTPUT: [1116] parse-server running on http://localhost:1337/parse**

4. Launch another Node.js command prompt

`cd C:\
parse-dashboard --appId com.test.parsetest --masterKey parsetestkey --serverURL "http://localhost:1337/parse" --appName ParseTest`
**OUTPUT: The dashboard is now available at http://0.0.0.0:4040/**

At the browser, I try to browse http://0.0.0.0:4040/, but it couldn't reach.